# Search for node doesn't auto expand folder or show child counter

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I have copied some code for the filter functionality for the fancytree from this link:  http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-ext-filter.html#

I injected the filter functionality into the tree that I have built but when I go to filter the tree for an item, the folders do not auto expand and the child counter does not appear.

What I have installed:

jquery.fancytree-all-deps

jquery.fanctree.filter

jquery-2.2.0

jquery-ui-1.11.1

I tried installing the versions that were specified in the source code of the link that I specified above but that did not help.  Is there anything that seems out of place?  I placed the filter properties in the correct place, included the filter extension, and included the key-up method to gather data from the user.

Everything else that I have attempted to do with this tree I have been able to do, but this seems to be tripping me up. Any help would be great!

```
$(function () {
$("#tree").fancytree({
    extensions: ["filter"],
    quicksearch: true,
    filter: {
        autoApply: true,   // Re-apply last filter if lazy data is loaded
        autoExpand: true, // Expand all branches that contain matches while filtered
        counter: true,     // Show a badge with number of matching child nodes near parent icons
        fuzzy: false,      // Match single characters in order, e.g. 'fb' will match 'FooBar'
        hideExpandedCounter: true,  // Hide counter badge if parent is expanded
        hideExpanders: false,       // Hide expanders if all child nodes are hidden by filter
        highlight: true,   // Highlight matches by wrapping inside <mark> tags
        leavesOnly: false, // Match end nodes only
        nodata: true,      // Display a 'no data' status node if result is empty
        mode: "dimm"       // Grayout unmatched nodes (pass "hide" to remove unmatched node instead)
    },
    icon: false,
    checkbox: true,
    selectMode: 3,
    source: treeStruc,
    lazyLoad: function (event, data) {
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();
        data.result = dfd.promise();
        scope.tree.parentSelectionState = data.node.data.preselected; 
        GetElementsForTree(data.node.key).done(function (value, dataReturned) {
            var lazyNodeValues = [];
            for (var l = 0; l < value.length; l++) {
                var element = value[l].Path.split('\\');
                element = element[element.length - 1];
                var obj = { title: element, key: value[l].Path, webId: value[l].WebId, preselected: scope.tree.parentSelectionState, lazy: true }; 
                lazyNodeValues.push(obj);
            }
            dfd.resolve(lazyNodeValues);
        });
    },
    loadChildren: function (event, data) {
        // Apply parent's state to new child nodes:
        data.node.fixSelection3AfterClick();$("#tree").fancytree("getTree").getNodeByKey(data.node.children[i].key).setExpanded(true);
    }
}); //End of $#tree
$('#tree').removeClass('r-hidden');                               



var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree");

/*
    * Event handlers for our little demo interface
    */
$("input[name=search]").keyup(function (e) {
    var n,
        tree = $.ui.fancytree.getTree(),
        args = "autoApply autoExpand fuzzy hideExpanders highlight leavesOnly nodata".split(" "),
        opts = {},
        filterFunc = $("#branchMode").is(":checked") ? tree.filterBranches : tree.filterNodes,
        match = $(this).val();

    $.each(args, function (i, o) {
        opts[o] = $("#" + o).is(":checked");
    });
    opts.mode = $("#hideMode").is(":checked") ? "hide" : "dimm";

    if (e && e.which === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE || $.trim(match) === "") {
        $("button#btnResetSearch").click();
        return;
    }
    if ($("#regex").is(":checked")) {
        // Pass function to perform match
        n = filterFunc.call(tree, function (node) {
            return new RegExp(match, "i").test(node.title);
        }, opts);
    } else {
        // Pass a string to perform case insensitive matching
        n = filterFunc.call(tree, match, opts);
    }
    $("button#btnResetSearch").attr("disabled", false);
    $("span#matches").text("(" + n + " matches)");
}).focus();

$("fieldset input:checkbox").change(function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id"),
        flag = $(this).is(":checked");

    // Some options can only be set with general filter options (not method args):
    switch (id) {
        case "counter":
        case "hideExpandedCounter":
            tree.options.filter[id] = flag;
            break;
    }
    tree.clearFilter();
    $("input[name=search]").keyup();
});
}); //End of $function
```

Comment: Not sure if this causes the problem, but if you're already including jquery ui, you should use jquery.fancytree-all instead of jquery.fancytree-all-deps

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Instead of storing the filter function in a variable,  I simply make the call "$("#tree").fancytree("getTree").filterNodes(match, { autoExpand: true, leavesOnly: false });" in the else clause of the "$("#regex").is(":checked")" if statement.  Also, the child count problem was due to the fact that the icons were set to false.  In order to see the child count, the icons have to be set to true.